# tasks environment vs. pgffor's foreach

Tags: tasks, pgffor

I want to `\foreach` on a list and create task (via package [`tasks`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tasks)) inside a question. A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{fp}
\def\pontlist{
2/3/1/4/,
5/1/-4/3/,
2/7/11/10/,
4/-3/5/7/,
-4/4/5/-7/,
-4/-4/4/4/,
3/7/-3/10/,
-1/-2/3/4/,
-1/3/-2/1/
}
\newcommand{\felezopont}[4]{
  \FPeval{\resx}{round( ( (#1)+(#3) )/2,1)}
  \FPeval{\resy}{round( ( (#2)+(#4) )/2,1)}
  \task $A(#1;#2)$, $B(#3;#4)$
  {$(\resx;\resy)$}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{question}
  Határozd meg a következő pontpárok felezőpontját!
  \begin{tasks}
    \foreach \ax/\ay/\bx/\by in \pontlist {
      \felezopont{\ax}{\ay}{\bx}{\by}
    }
  \end{tasks}
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

Without `\begin{tasks} ... \end{tasks}` works well but the use of `tasks` environment causes an error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.33 \end{question}
```

What do I use wrong?

Comment: The  `\tasks`  environments requites a series of `\task` commands. Would you use a list environment without `\item`s?

Comment: Yes, I think maybe it's the problem. But how can I do it? I tried to place `\task` before `\felezopont` (not inside `\felezopont`) but it didn't work.

If you've another idea instead of `pgffor` it's OK for me. The most important thing: work properly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that the `tasks` environment actually sees the `\task`s. They can't be hidden in a macro (even if it were expandable). BTW: `tasks` is a package of its own – `exsheets` just loads it.

Here is a possible solution:

```
\newcommand*\pontlist{
  2/3/1/4/,
  5/1/-4/3/,
  2/7/11/10/,
  4/-3/5/7/,
  -4/4/5/-7/,
  -4/-4/4/4/,
  3/7/-3/10/,
  -1/-2/3/4/,
  -1/3/-2/1/
}

% remove \task from the definition:
\newcommand{\felezopont}[4]{
  \FPeval{\resx}{round( ( (#1)+(#3) )/2,1)}
  \FPeval{\resy}{round( ( (#2)+(#4) )/2,1)}
  $A(#1;#2)$, $B(#3;#4)$
  {$(\resx;\resy)$}
}

% build list for the tasks environment:
\newcommand*\taskslist{}
\foreach \ax/\ay/\bx/\by in \pontlist {
  \begingroup
  \edef\x{\endgroup
    \expandafter\noexpand\csname g@addto@macro\endcsname
    \noexpand\taskslist{\noexpand\task\noexpand\felezopont{\ax}{\ay}{\bx}{\by}}%
  }\x
}

% needed helper macros so the tasks environment actually sees \task macros:
\newcommand\switchtwo[2]{#2#1}
\newcommand\expandsecond[2]{%
  \expandafter\switchtwo\expandafter{#1}{#2}%
}
```

and then:

```
\expandsecond\taskslist
{\begin{tasks}}
\end{tasks}
```

This solution has the disadvantage that it cannot be used in an environment like the `question` environment of the `exsheets` package because `\begin{tasks}` is hidden from it and `\end{tasks}` is not. But the solution to this problem is simple: hide it in a macro completely:

```
\newcommand*\printtaskslist{%
  \expandsecond\taskslist
  {\begin{tasks}}
  \end{tasks}%
}
```

and then

```
\begin{question}
  Text
  \printtaskslist
\end{question}
```

[image]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{exsheets,tasks}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{fp}

\newcommand*\pontlist{
  2/3/1/4/,
  5/1/-4/3/,
  2/7/11/10/,
  4/-3/5/7/,
  -4/4/5/-7/,
  -4/-4/4/4/,
  3/7/-3/10/,
  -1/-2/3/4/,
  -1/3/-2/1/
}

% remove \task from the definition:
\newcommand{\felezopont}[4]{
  \FPeval{\resx}{round( ( (#1)+(#3) )/2,1)}
  \FPeval{\resy}{round( ( (#2)+(#4) )/2,1)}
  $A(#1;#2)$, $B(#3;#4)$
  {$(\resx;\resy)$}
}

% build list for the tasks environment:
\newcommand*\taskslist{}
\foreach \ax/\ay/\bx/\by in \pontlist {
  \begingroup
  \edef\x{\endgroup
    \expandafter\noexpand\csname g@addto@macro\endcsname
    \noexpand\taskslist{\noexpand\task\noexpand\felezopont{\ax}{\ay}{\bx}{\by}}%
  }\x
}

% needed helper macros so the tasks environment actually sees \task macros:
\newcommand\switchtwo[2]{#2#1}
\newcommand\expandsecond[2]{%
  \expandafter\switchtwo\expandafter{#1}{#2}%
}

\newcommand*\printtaskslist{%
  \expandsecond\taskslist
  {\begin{tasks}}
  \end{tasks}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
  Text
  \printtaskslist
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Without using `question` environment works well. But how can I place into a `question` (as I wrote in my question's MWE)?  `\begin{question}Text of question... \expandsecond\taskslist{\begin{tasks}}\end{tasks}\end{question}` doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, yes. I know what's going wrong then. I'll update the answer as soon as I'll find the time.

Comment: Thank you. I hope you can find a solution - my life would be easier :)

Comment: @uzsolt see the updated answer

Comment: Oh, great, thank you, it works well! When I have time I'll learn more about LaTeX (your solution isn't too clear for me). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You need to prepare the `\task` list in advance and deliver it *expanded* in the `tasks` environment. Here's a way to do it in with the help of `xparse` and `expl3`.

Please, avoid the obsolete package `t1enc` and also `utf8x`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % NOT t1enc
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % NOT utf8x
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\usepackage{xparse,exsheets}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% function for print the coordinates from the input x1/y1/x2/y2/
\cs_new:Npn \uzsolt_felezopont:w #1/#2/#3/#4/
 {
  $A(#1;#2)$,~$B(#3;#4)$~$(\fp_eval:n { (#1+#3)/2 }; \fp_eval:n { (#2+#4)/2 })$
 }
% macro for making the tasks environment
\cs_new_protected:Nn \uzsolt_pointtask:n
 {
  \begin{tasks}
  #1
  \end{tasks}
 }
% the variant that accepts a token list variable as its argument
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \uzsolt_pointtask:n { V }

% a variable for later usage
\tl_new:N \l_uzsolt_pointtask_tl

% the main macro that accepts an implicit list of points as argument
\NewDocumentCommand{\pointtask}{m}
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l_uzsolt_pointtask_tl
  \clist_map_inline:Nn #1
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_uzsolt_pointtask_tl { \task \uzsolt_felezopont:w ##1 }
   }
  \uzsolt_pointtask:V \l_uzsolt_pointtask_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\newcommand\pontlist{
  2/3/1/4/,
  5/1/-4/3/,
  2/7/11/10/,
  4/-3/5/7/,
  -4/4/5/-7/,
  -4/-4/4/4/,
  3/7/-3/10/,
  -1/-2/3/4/,
  -1/3/-2/1/
}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
Határozd meg a következő pontpárok felezőpontját!
\pointtask\pontlist
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

On the other hand, if you define `\pointtask` with

```
  \clist_map_inline:nn {#1}
```

instead of `\clist_map_inline:Nn #1`, the input could be

```
\begin{question}
Határozd meg a következő pontpárok felezőpontját!
\pointtask{
  2/3/1/4/,
  5/1/-4/3/,
  2/7/11/10/,
  4/-3/5/7/,
  -4/4/5/-7/,
  -4/-4/4/4/,
  3/7/-3/10/,
  -1/-2/3/4/,
  -1/3/-2/1/
}
\end{question}
```

(no previous definition of `\pontlist` is necessary) which, in my opinion, would be preferable.

[image]

Comment: The definition of `\pointlist` is preferable for me: I'm re-using it in the next questions (in the MWE can't see). Thanks for your answer and suggestions (utf8, t1enc) too.