# Measuring List Items in Tasks and Making Changes Accordingly

Tags: lengths, tasks, measure

I made the following list for MCQs using `tasks`package.

The problem is I need a command that can measure the contents of all the `\task`s per question and determine the maximum width among them. And in case it is larger than a certain width (~200pt), it should change `\task` to `\task*` throughout the choices in the current question to give the output at the bottom.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[papersize={600pt,800pt},top=50pt,left=50pt,right=50pt,bottom=50pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tasks}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\normalsize{\@setfontsize\normalsize{13.5pt}{17pt}}
\normalsize  
\makeatother

\definecolor{ChoiceGray}{RGB}{204,204,204}

\newcommand*\Choice[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-5pt]
    \node [gray,minimum width=22pt,minimum height=22pt,draw=ChoiceGray,rounded corners] {\large #1};
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\newcounter{ChoiceLabel}
\newcommand*\ChoiceLabel{%
    \refstepcounter{ChoiceLabel}%
    \hskip1em\llap{\Choice{\Alph{ChoiceLabel}}}}%

\newcommand*{\MCQ}[1]{\setcounter{ChoiceLabel}{0}\begin{tasks}[after-item-skip=3mm,label=\ChoiceLabel](2)
        #1
\end{tasks}}


\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.,leftmargin=1cm]

        \item{Question text here.
            \MCQ{
                \task Some choice
                \task Another choice
                \task A choice with larger width that will break on two lines
                \task The last one
            }
        }

    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[papersize={600pt,800pt},top=50pt,left=50pt,right=50pt,bottom=50pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tasks}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\normalsize{\@setfontsize\normalsize{13.5pt}{17pt}}
\normalsize  
\makeatother

\definecolor{ChoiceGray}{RGB}{204,204,204}

\newcommand*\Choice[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-5pt]
    \node [gray,minimum width=22pt,minimum height=22pt,draw=ChoiceGray,rounded corners] {\large #1};
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\newcounter{ChoiceLabel}
\newcommand*\ChoiceLabel{%
    \refstepcounter{ChoiceLabel}%
    \hskip1em\llap{\Choice{\Alph{ChoiceLabel}}}}%

\newcommand*{\MCQ}[1]{\setcounter{ChoiceLabel}{0}\begin{tasks}[after-item-skip=3mm,label=\ChoiceLabel](2)
        #1
\end{tasks}}


\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.,leftmargin=1cm]

        \item{Question text here.
            \MCQ{
                \task* Some choice
                \task* Another choice
                \task* A choice with larger width that will break on two lines
                \task* The last one
            }
        }

    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I use `listofitems` to initially parse the argument of `\MCQ` with `\task` as a separator.  It loops through the parsed `\tasklist` measuring the longest one.  If that longest one exceeds the threshold, here 200pt, it builds a token list that substitutes `\task*` wherever there had been `\task` in the original argument.

The original syntax of the OP is preserved.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[papersize={600pt,800pt},top=50pt,left=50pt,right=50pt,bottom=50pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tasks}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\normalsize{\@setfontsize\normalsize{13.5pt}{17pt}}
\normalsize  
\makeatother

\definecolor{ChoiceGray}{RGB}{204,204,204}

\newcommand*\Choice[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-5pt]
    \node [gray,minimum width=22pt,minimum height=22pt,draw=ChoiceGray,rounded corners] {\large #1};
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\newcounter{ChoiceLabel}
\newcommand*\ChoiceLabel{%
    \refstepcounter{ChoiceLabel}%
    \hskip1em\llap{\Choice{\Alph{ChoiceLabel}}}}%

\newtoks\tasktoks
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand*{\MCQ}[1]{%
  \setsepchar{\task}%
  \ignoreemptyitems%
  \readlist*\tasklist{#1}%
  \def\longtask{0pt}%
  \foreachitem\taskitem\in\tasklist{% MEASURE THE LONGEST TASK
    \setbox0=\hbox{\taskitem}%
    \ifdim\wd0>\longtask\relax\edef\longtask{\the\wd0}\fi%
  }%
  \setcounter{ChoiceLabel}{0}%
  \ifdim\longtask>200pt\relax% FOR LONG TASKS, EMPLOY \task*
    \foreachitem\taskitem\in\tasklist{%
      \tasktoks\expandafter{\the\tasktoks\task*}%
      \tasktoks\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
         \expandafter\the\expandafter\tasktoks\taskitem}%
    }%
  \else%
    \tasktoks{#1}%
  \fi%
  \def\tmp{ \begin{tasks}[after-item-skip=3mm,label=\ChoiceLabel](2)}%
  \expandafter\tmp\the\tasktoks%
  \end{tasks}%
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.,leftmargin=1cm]
        \item{Question text here.
            \MCQ{
                \task Some choice
                \task Another choice
                \task Third choice
                \task The last one
            }
        }
    \end{enumerate}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.,leftmargin=1cm]
        \item{Question text here.
            \MCQ{
                \task Some choice
                \task Another choice
                \task A choice with larger width that will break on two lines
                \task The last one
            }
        }
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you a can accept  a (slightly) modified input of the task list like :

```
\MCQ{Some choice\\
Another choice\\
A choice with a larger width that will break on two lines\\
The last one
}
```

below is a working solution. 
It uses parsing and iteration from package `listofitems` and a few functions of `etoolbox` package. Th key idea is to first iterate to find the maximl width, an secondly to iterate to build the body of the `tasks` environment. This is made rather elaborated because of the very special handling of `tasks` content (I used for that the answer from *clemens* for the question [tasks-environment-vs-pgffors-foreach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354242/tasks-environment-vs-pgffors-foreach)). If you would use a more standard environment, everything can be codded in four or five lines.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[papersize={600pt,800pt},top=50pt,left=50pt,right=50pt,bottom=50pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\normalsize{\@setfontsize\normalsize{13.5pt}{17pt}}
\normalsize  
\makeatother

\definecolor{ChoiceGray}{RGB}{204,204,204}

\newcommand*\Choice[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-5pt]
    \node [gray,minimum width=22pt,minimum height=22pt,draw=ChoiceGray,rounded corners] {\large #1};
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\newcounter{ChoiceLabel}
\newcommand*\ChoiceLabel{%
    \refstepcounter{ChoiceLabel}%
    \hskip1em\llap{\Choice{\Alph{ChoiceLabel}}}%
}
%------------------------
\newcommand\switchtwo[2]{#2#1}
\newcommand\expandsecond[2]{\expandafter\switchtwo\expandafter{#1}{#2}}
\newlength{\tsklenmax}
\newcommand{\setTaskLenMax}[1]{\setlength{\tsklenmax}{#1}}
\newcommand{\maxdim}[2]{\ifdimgreater{#1}{#2}{#1}{#2}}

\newcommand*{\MCQ}[1]{
% initize
\ifdef{\taskslist}{\renewcommand*\taskslist{}}{\newcommand*\taskslist{}}
\ifdef{\thetasks}{\let\thetasks\undefined}{}
\newlength{\tsklen}\newlength{\tsklentempmax}
\setlength{\tsklentempmax}{\tsklenmax}
% read tasks
\setsepchar{\\} \ignoreemptyitems
\greadlist*\thetasks{#1}
% find maximal width
\foreachitem\atask\in\thetasks{
    \settowidth{\tsklen}{\atask}
    \setlength{\tsklentempmax}{\maxdim{\tsklen}{\tsklentempmax}}
}
% choose task version
\ifdimgreater{\tsklentempmax}{\tsklenmax}{\def\usestar{\noexpand\task*}}{\def\usestar{\noexpand\task}}
% populate task list
\foreachitem\atask\in\thetasks{
  \begingroup
  \edef\x{\endgroup
    \expandafter\noexpand\csname g@addto@macro\endcsname
    \noexpand\taskslist{\usestar \atask}%
  }\x
}
% display tasks
\setcounter{ChoiceLabel}{0}%
\expandsecond\taskslist
{\begin{tasks}[after-item-skip=3mm,label=\ChoiceLabel](2)}
\end{tasks}
}

\begin{document}

\setTaskLenMax{250pt}   

\begin{enumerate}
\item question 1
\MCQ{Some choice\\
Another choice\\
A choice with a larger width that will break on two lines\\
The last one
}
\item Question 2
\MCQ{Some choice\\
Another choice\\
With reduced larger width \\
The last one
}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Resulting in:
[image]

The new `MCQ` command and its auxillary functions/length are defined at the end of the preamble.

Obviously, as you already load `tikz` to create the fancy labels, you could replace list handling and iteration by those of `pgf`.

Comment: Ha.  I made my solution without looking at yours.  I upvote because of their extreme similarity (though I did use tokens rather than `\g@addto@macro`).  In addition, and importantly, I did preserve the syntax of the OP.